# in springboot after adding dependency file i have /newart.jsp throw where i do mistake

Tags: java, spring-boot, dependencies

Spring boot this i used but i got error while runing
Its my Java File

```
    import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
    import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
    @Controller
    public class MusicConcert {
    @RequestMapping(value = "/newart", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public String newart() {
            System.out.println("sdf");
            return "newart.jsp";
        }
    }
```

It my hello.jsp File

```
 <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Insert title here</title>
    </head>
    <body>
     hi this is java
    </body>
    </html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema- 
instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.telusco</groupId>
<artifactId>respect</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>respect</name>
<description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>



<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat/tomcat-jasper -->
<dependency>

<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
<version>9.0.33</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Error is :
Whitelabel Error Page
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Sun May 03 23:57:58 IST 2020
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
/newart.jsp

Comment: is a file `newart.jsp` existing? maybe you want to rename `hello.jsp` into `newart.jsp`?

Comment: Yeah I did that but still it's showing

Comment: Can you share your `application.properties` or yml file? Where is `newart.jsp` located

Comment: im not add any properties in  'application.proprties'

Answer (score 0):

Please replace dependency

```
<groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
<artifactId>tomcat-jasper</artifactId>
<version>9.0.33</version>
</dependency>
</dependencies>
```

in `pom.xml` with dependencies

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
      <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
      <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
```

In addition please ensure that your `application.properties` contains

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

and that your jsp files are located in folder `/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/jsp`.
In your controller it is sufficient to execute `return /newart` instead of `return /newart.jsp`.

Comment: am i missing  any config while installing any files r something

Comment: I could reproduce your error and fix it as described in my answer. Can you check again if you changed everything as described?